# What is the etymology of Tibetan ཁང་ [khang]?

Tags: etymology, comparative-linguistics, sprachbund, sino-tibetan

I've just discovered that ***ཁང་*** [Wylie: khang], the Tibetan word for 'building' used as a part in many everyday vocabulary items sounds strangely familiar to the word of the same meaning in Farsi, which is ***خانه*** [khåna].

The Tibetan vocabulary stock includes such samples as

**སྨན་ཁང་** [sman.khang], a hospital

***ཟ་ཁང་*** [za.khang], a restaurant

***ཚོང་ཁང་*** [tshong.khang], a shop

***ཆང་ཁང་*** [chang.khang], a bar

***ཇ་ཁང་*** [ja.khang], a tea house

and so on.

Given the historical and cultural connections between the Muslim and Tibetan cultures, is this word a loan from Farsi or is it of Sino-Tibetan stock?

If so, what are the cognate words in other Sino-Tibetan languages?